# XL VBA Macro for inserting blank cells right based on criteria i.e. Column B contains a $

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro to insert 2 cells moving existing data right. Sounds easy but been at it all day.

The issue is that the column B contains text and currency. If the cell contains currency, say $4661.52, I need to insert 2 cells, moving existing currency data right.

The length varies as does where the currency cells are. Late in the day 
and confused.

Tried this and many variations :

```
Public Sub insertcells()
Const CLIENT As String = "B"
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      With ActiveSheet
         Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, CLIENT).End(xlUp).Row
         For i = Lastrow To 1 Step -1
             If Cells(i, CLIENT).Value2 Like "$*" Then
                 .Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
             End If
         Next i
     End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please make proper formation of your question with code indentation and other edits. This will make your question more understandable. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code.

```
Public Sub insertcells()
Const CLIENT As String = "B"
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      With ActiveSheet
         Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, CLIENT).End(xlUp).Row
         For i = Lastrow To 1 Step -1
             If Cells(i, CLIENT).Value2 Like "$*" Or IsNumeric(Cells(i, CLIENT).Value) Then
                 .Cells(i, CLIENT).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                 .Cells(i, CLIENT).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
             End If
         Next i
     End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats nearly there!! Thanks. Just one further bit, to move 2 cells right?

Comment: just repeat the line .Cells(i, CLIENT).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove.... and it will work as you wish. I've updated the answer. Please check.